# How to customize UI of Swagger (drf-yasg) to use dark mode?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui, drf-yasg

So we have done our Django API documentation setup using `drf-yasg`, and I was wondering if it's possible to use dark mode in the documentation screen.
For reference, the screen looks something like this:

[image]